# Website doesn't scroll on Android mobile

Tags: android, css, scroll

I have been reading a lot but I can't find a solution.

I'm working on a website that works perfectly in Desktop, iPhone and iPad, but it doesn't scroll in Android mobile.

I add to the mobile @media:

```
body {
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

And the header and footer have position as relative (I read 'fixed' value does make troubles with Android) but it not solve the problem.
Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: The problem description "does not scroll" is very broad and can have many issues. Does the problem occur on all mobiles phones? All mobile browser? Did you try using the browser developer tools and simulate a mobile phone like screen size?

Comment: Thanks Capricorn. Apparently it happens in all phones and browsers. I simulated in chrome device toolbar and it works, which is weird because then it doesn't in the phones.

Comment: The CSS behaves a bit differently with your `float`. It is possible that the body overflowed but it had a fixed height in mobile. You can use chrome Element tool to find out what's the height of body and what is overflowing.

Comment: Thanks nightgaunt, it was solved!